# Where should find_package be called in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

Including external libraries in a cmake project is usually performed using `find_package()`.

But in a large multi-application / multi-library project, it is typical for some 3rd-party and/or system libraries to be used by multiple applications and libraries.

Where should `find_package()` for these common libraries be called?

1. In the `CMakeLists.txt` file for each executable/library that needs them?
2. Or, once in a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file?

The first options seems to be a more modular approach, but the associated `find_package()` scripts are executed for each library/executable that uses them.  This can slow down the configuration step.

The second option is more efficient, but looks a bit too much like a global variable to me.

Comment: I think it should go in the top-level CMakeLists.txt, and then they should be used with something like `target_link_libraries(my_exe PUBLIC Boost::system)`

Comment: Sounds like "**opinion-base**" question for me. Second and futher invocations of `find_package` for the same package usually takes a little time, because it **does not search again** but reuses cached results from the first invocation. So in case of per-directory invocation of `find_package` perfomance needn't neccessary to be a problem. (But, as usual with performance, one should measure it before draw the conclusions.)

Answer (score 2):

I would distinguish between subprojects/-directories that might be standalone packages on their own (or already are) and those that exclusively reflect the source code structure.

- In the first case, `find_package` should clearly be in the subdirectory `CMakeLists.txt` to allow for extracting the subdirectory for a standalone build or distribution. Inefficiency of the configuration step should not be a concern here, as the configuration of a build is not performed that often.
- In the second case, I would prefer `find_package` calls in the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt`. If you don't use the variables set by these calls to populate global variables but use `target_link_libraries` instead (as suggested in the comments), this should be clean enough. Sometimes though, found packages do not export proper targets to link against, but rather define some include path variables and the like. Then, it should be easy to define your own `INTERFACE` library that encapsulate these flags/paths as usage requirements and propagate them transitively when linked via `target_link_libraries` again.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me... When I do a `find_package` in the top level `CMakeLists.txt` it gets found, but the target then appears unknown in `subdir/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @CarloWood And have you made sure that `find_package` is invoked _before_ you `add_subdirectory` `subdir/CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: I figured it out: a find_package must appear in every CMakeLists.txt that explicitly uses the target. Aka, if foo/CMakeLists.txt uses bar::bar then foo/CMakeLists.txt must do a find_package(bar). There is no way to do it elsewhere. With 'uses' I mean you type it out. If it gets linked in as a dependency of something else then there is no need for the find_package.